# Ionic Starter App testing - www directory not dound

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to this platform and I am following the guidelines at the docs. I am trying to test the app using `ionic serve` CLI response is that there are 3 addresses....I choose localhost and an error comes up - ""www" directory not found. please make sure the working directory is ionic project"
I need help working around this.

I am working on windows 7.

Comment: Did you cd into the directory for the Ionic project?

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you try to run your project into sub-directory which do not contains ionic project. Verify if you have 'www' folder inside your ionic project or you mistakenly went inside other sub-directory and trying to execute 'ionic serve' command.

Answer (score 0):

After creating you project. The cmd screen will give you the directory of newly created project. Therefore in the CMD type this command:

```
cd yourprojectname
```

eg

```
cd myionicproject
```

after that command is completed enter command:

```
$ ionic serve
```